# Django: is_authenticated and is_anonymous both return true after logout

Tags: python, django, templates, authentication, django-registration

I am using django-registration, and just set it up.

```
{{user.is_authenticated }}
```

is true, even though i went already to /accounts/logout/ and logged the user out.

```
{{user.is_anonymous }}
```

returns true also. According to django docs, those two should be different:

> is_anonymous: Always returns False. This is a way of differentiating User and AnonymousUser objects. Generally, you should prefer using is_authenticated() to this method.

and

> is_authenticated: Always returns True. This is a way to tell if the user has been authenticated. This does not imply any permissions, and doesn't check if the user is active - it only indicates that the user has provided a valid username and password.

I am using the standard views that come with django-registration and haven't touched them yet. In the tempalate i have the following code:

```
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
{% user }}
{% if user.is_anonymous %}
    is anonymous
{% endif $}
{% else %}
    gotta login
{% endif %}
```

Where would the problem be? I will be really thankful!

UPDATE:
i have noticed that on the homepage, it both is_authenticated and id_anonymous return True, while if i go to /accounts/login before loging in, only is_anonymous returns true as it should be. And also, on the homepage, i have the following view if that helps:

```
def home(request):
    return render_jinja(request, 'index.html', blah = 'ga')
```

UPDATE 2:
print(request.user.is_authenticated()) gives False. Then, i have:

```
return render_jinja(request, 'index.html', blah = 'ga')
```

and in the template, user.is_authenticated returns FALSE.

UPDATE 3:
If i use render_to_response, instead of render_jinja, all is good. still don't know how to fix this though :(

Comment: I'm afraid I can't reproduce this behaviour at all in a newly created project and app. Which version of Django are you using? How are you logging the user in, and then subsequently logging the user out?

Comment: If you tell me how to check which version of django i have, i will be more than happy to check! shot in the dark - 1.2

Comment: Since I am using this open source django-registration app, i am logging at the accounts/login/ and logging out at the accounts/logout. and if you tell me how to paste code in comment, i can paste the view from those links

Comment: Here is a snipped from the urls file:
url(r'^logout/$', auth_views.logout, {'template_name': 'registration/logout.html'}, name='auth_logout'),

Comment: i found out how to tell django version and result is: (1,2,0, 'beta', 1)

Comment: Thanks @mgPePe. Since Django underwent a few changes to the auth module in 1.2, please try installing the production version of django (Django 1.2 has been out since May 2010, and I note you are still using beta 1), and then re-installing the django-registration app.

Comment: Your tags and variables in the template are incorrect, at least in the above text. You have {% user }} and {% endif $}. Not sure if that would contribute (and likely your actual template doesn't have these errors).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It seems like you are trying to figure out two things at once; what is the correct way to use jinja templates and what is the deal with User/AnonymousUser.  Maybe try to figure out these problems one at a time.

I have no experience with jinja but you may want to check and make sure that you are taking [differences between jinja and django template syntax](http://jinja.pocoo.org/switching/#django) into account.  The biggest difference I know of is that a method call requires explicit parenthesis. So the is_authenticated and is_anonymous calls in your example need parenthesis.

```
Jinja style {{ user.is_authenticated() }}
Django style {{ user.is_authenticated }}
```

If that does not solve the problem, try installing [django-debug-toolbar](https://github.com/robhudson/django-debug-toolbar) and take a look at the context for your template.  Check and see if `user` is None or an object (User or AnonymousUser).

You can also read up on [AnonymousUser](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#anonymous-users) and see an example of [checking for an authenticated user](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#authentication-in-web-requests) in the docs.  In a nutshell, for an AnonymousUser object is_anonymous() always returns True instead of False and is_authenticated() always returns False instead of True.

Comment: Awesome. I thought I solved the problem more or less, but that gives such a nice overview, I will be checking all of those things, gracias!

Comment: Note for future readers:  is_authenticated is a property now, so some of the information here is outdated.

Answer (score 4):

Smack on the head. I read somewhere:

> if user.is_authenticated:
>       ....# Always true, since it is a method!

And so, instead of having {{user.is_authenticated}} in template, it should be {{user.is_authenticated()}}

Comment: Not so in Django 1.8. Be careful, as is_authenticated returns a non-callable bool (basically a property, not a function).