# is_authenticated returns True for AnonymousUser

Tags: django, django-authentication

I am struggling with `is_authenticated` returning `True` when I'm not logged in:

```
u = request.user
if u.is_authenticated:
    raise Exception('I am said to be authenticated, but I really am not.')
```

To clarify, Django debug view correctly identifies `u` as an `AnonymousUser`:

```
u   <django.contrib.auth.models.AnonymousUser object at 0x9e76f4cc>
```

Even more odd, **inside the template** `is_anonymous` works fine:

```
{% if not request.user.is_authenticated %}
    We are anonymous.
{% endif %}
```

Why is that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Django: is\_authenticated and is\_anonymous both return true after logout](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4298387/django-is-authenticated-and-is-anonymous-both-return-true-after-logout)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

It's a [method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.is_authenticated), not a property. You need to call it:

```
if u.is_authenticated():
```

Of course, in a template, Django [calls methods for you](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/templates/#accessing-method-calls) automatically.

Comment: In modern versions of Django, this is no longer true. `is_authenticated` is a property. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.is_authenticated

Answer (score 6):

`is_authenticated` is a method, so you need some parentheses there.  Otherwise, `u.is_authenticated` is the function object, which is a `True`ish value.

In the template language, functions with no arguments are evaluated as functions, so that's why you're good there.

Comment: Oh, thanks. This makes perfect sense. One of those subtle bugs you may not train your eye for after years of working with a language that only allows booleans in the condition.

Comment: Yes indeed you gotta be careful; old => new: request.user.is_authenticated => request.user.is_authenticated and request.user.is_authenticated == True; 
if not request.user.is_authenticated: => if not request.user.is_authenticated or request.user.is_authenticated == False:.